# Bilinear form and quotient space

Tags: quotient-spaces, bilinear-form

Let $U,V$ be two finite dimensional vector spaces of a field $K$ and let $f:U \times V \to K$a bilinear form. The set $U_0 = \{u \in U: f(u,v) = 0,\forall v \in V \}$ is called the left kernel of $f$ and $V_0 = \{v \in V: f(u,v) =0, \forall u \in U\}$ is called the right kernel of $f$.

Show that $\dim U/U_0 = \dim V/V_0$ and the kernels of $g: U/U_0 \times V/V_0 \to K$ given by $g(u+U_0,v+V_0) = f(u,v)$ is the null space.

The second statement is obvious, but how can I show the first?? that is, $\dim U/U_0 = \dim V/V_0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the bilinear form, you get a linear map $U/U_0 \to (V/V_0)^*$ and this is injective. Now compare dimensions and you get an inequality (the spaces are finite-dimensional, so dual spaces do not change the dimension).

Comment: Did you mean $h: U/U_0 \to (V/V_0)^{*}$ given by $h(u+ U_0) = \phi_u$, where $\phi_u:V/V_0 \to K$ is given by $\phi_u(v+V_0) = f(u,v)$??

Comment: Yes, certainly. View $f(u,v)$ as a linear function on $V$ with $u$ fixed. Adjusting $u$ or $v$ by elements of $U_0$ and $V_0$ has no effect, so you can regard $u$ and $v$ as elements of $U/U_0$ and $V/V_0$.

Comment: ok, thank you :)

Comment: I've found another trouble, I was thinking that the second statement is obvious, but it is not to obvious.  To prove that $g$ is well- defined I need to show that if $u_1-u_2 \in U_0$ and $v_1-v_2 \in V_0$ then $f(u_1,v_1) = f(u_2,v_2)$, but how I can do that?